# Facebook App - Page not found in iPad/iPhone works fine in desktop

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-page

I apologise in advance if this been asked before, but I have spent 2 days googling/trying different methods to no avail.

1. I have built an app for a client.
2. It works fine on desktop. No problems.
3. When I click on the link to the app on my iPhone iPad, its says "Page not found"

Client page (where app 'Win With Parade' has been added:
https://www.facebook.com/ParadeSwindon

The app in question:
https://www.facebook.com/ParadeSwindon/app_155622657928426

I have tried Authentication 'Native/Desktop' with no improvement.

I have attached a screen shot of the setup, again works fine on desktop, 
just fails in iOS Facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access page applications from mobile native apps (not yet anyway)

see : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7226742/910325

Comment: Thank you for this link, I will read in-depth before asking any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to login first in your iPhone. goto -> setting and Facebook enter username and password then run your app. it will work. in IOS 6.0